# Show that $\sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{1}{b^2+c^2+5bc-a^2} \leq \frac{\sqrt3}{8S}$ for a triangle with sides $a$, $b$, $c$ and area $S$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, substitution, geometric-inequalities, jensen-inequality

Let be $a$, $b$, $c$ sides of a triangle and $S$ his area. Prove that $$\sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{1}{b^2+c^2+5bc-a^2} \leq \frac{\sqrt3}{8S}$$

---

My idea: $b^2+c^2-a^2 = 2bc \cos A$, so the inequality is equivalent to: 
$$\sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{\sin A}{2\cos A+5}\leq\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$$

Comment: From where does it come?

Comment: i dont know..i have the problem from a friend..its for preparing olympiad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, you can use Jensen because
$$\left(\frac{\sin\alpha}{5+2\cos\alpha}\right)''=\frac{\sin\alpha(10\cos\alpha-17)}{(5+2\cos\alpha)^3}<0$$ for all $0<\alpha<\pi.$

Comment: thanks but i dont know what actually means ''

Comment: (sin alpha / 5+2cos alpha ) ^ " ?

Comment: I think he meant the second derivative with respect to $\alpha$

Comment: @mathematiciangrade8 It means that $f(x)=\frac{\sin{x}}{5+2\cos{x}}$ is a concave function and your inequality follows from the Jensen's inequality.